# On group with special properties

Tags: group-theory

Is there a group $G$ with two the following properties:?

i) $Aut(G)$ is not nilpotent, where $Aut(G)$ is the full automorphism group  of  $G$.

ii) There exists an element $1\neq x\in G$ of order odd such that $\alpha(x)=x$, for all $\alpha\in Aut(G)$.

My attempt: All finite abelian groups have not these properties.

Comment: The second property holds trivially, since the identity has order $1$ and is a fixed point for any automorphism.

Comment: If you have an example $G$ for (ii) with $Aut(G)$ nilpotent, you could try $G\times A_5$ instead.

Comment: We know that if ‎$‎G‎$ ‎is a finite group whose automorphism group ‎is nilpotent  such that ‎$‎G‎$ ‎is ‎not ‎cyclic ‎of ‎odd order, ‎then ‎‎$G$ has ‎is ‎ ‎non-trivial  element that is a fixed point for any automorphismgroup. Also  there exist groups of order $3^6$ with automorphism of group of order $3^7,3^8,3^9$ and $3^{10}$.

Comment: Take your (nilpotent) group $G$ of order $3^6$, which has a (central) element $x$ fulfilling (ii). For any simple group $S$ the group $G\times S$ fulfills (i) and (ii) as both $S$ and $G$ are characteristic subgroups (and therefore $Aut(G\times S) = Aut(G)\times Aut(S)$).

Comment: @j.p. In (i) $Aut$ to be non nilpotent, but $Aut(G\times S)$ may be nilpotent.

Comment: @A.G $Aut(G\times S)$ contains $Aut(S)$ with $S$ simple. With simple I meant non-cyclic simple (sorry for not stating this), so this is surely not nilpotent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the non-abelian group of order 63 satisfies the properties.

I checked that with GAP.

```
gap> G := SmallGroup(63, 1);;
gap> A := AutomorphismGroup(G);;
gap> IsNilpotent(A);
false
gap> Fixed := Filtered(G, g -> ForAll(A, a -> g = g^a));; #including 1
gap> List(Fixed, Order);
[ 1, 3, 3 ]
```